# Let is not showing the value of variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Have this very simple snippet:

```js
let pizza ='Marguerita';

console.log(pizza);
```

The above snippet works in that run snippet, but this code is not working in my browser Google Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit), in console it appears always as UNDEFINED.
I have also cleared the cache but still shows undefined. Anyone can explain the possible cause?

Thanks!

[image: Chrome snapshot]

Comment: Perhaps `console.log` has been redefined on that page to do nothing. That `undefined` is just the return value of `log` afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the text box used to filter the output has a value that causes the output to be empty.
When I debug a program, I often forget to empty the search box, and I can't find the specified output.
[image: console output with filter]
[image: console output without filter]

And the level in the drop-down box here will also affect the output. For example, the output here will disappear as long as you cancel the info.
[image: console output with info]
[image: console output without info]

Answer (score -3):

Dude, you always get 1-undefined in the end. There is nothing wrong with the code. Just try to uninstall chrome and then reinstall it.

What I got is:

[image]

1-undefined always stays at the bottom, that is not the value of `pizza` if you are getting confused. Just try reinstall chrome, there might be some bug there, in your version or installation.